# How to load url of clicked div on refresh?

Tags: jquery, html

So i have mainpage.php where I have div as follows:-

```
<div id="home" class="menu_align">Home</div>
<div id="write" class="menu_align">Write</div>
<div id="main_content"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#main_content").load('home.php');
});
$("#home").click(function(){
$("#main_content").load('home.php');
});
$("#write").click(function(){
$("#main_content").load('write.php');
});
</script>
```

So what I want here is that when user visits the page for first time it should load home.php as it is included in document.ready but when user clicks on write it should load write.php even after refresh, how to achieve this functionality ?

Comment: You may have to pass a variable to the URL during the click.

Comment: What variable should I pass ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple problem. See one way to approach it below:

```
<!-- Link to be clicked below -->

<a href="page-to-link-to.html#stop-here"> Link </a>
```

The above assumes that the `page` you want to link to is named `page-to-link-to.html` and the `div` you want it to scroll to on the `page` has the `id` `stop-here`.

When the `link` is clicked, the called `page` will open and jump to the `div` referenced with `#`.

Hope this helps.